# WPF CheckBox Command inside a Listview DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, datatemplate

My CheckBox Command does not work. I want to pass the SelectedItem of the ListView to the Command when the SelectedItem is checked or unchecked, but the Command does not execute at all. I also suspect my CommandParameter is not configured correctly?

I am pretty sure the problem is because the CheckBox is within a ListView DataTemplate.

Can someone show me how to set this up? I tried to follow examples I found, but nothing seems to work. thanks.

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvReferralSource" ItemsSource="{Binding ReferralSourceTypeObsCollection}" Style="{StaticResource TypeListViewStyle}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <CheckBox x:Name="ckbReferralIsChecked" Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding Active}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyleBase2}"
       Command="{Binding CheckBoxIsChecked}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=SelectedItem}">
      </CheckBox>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**CODE**

```
private ICommand _CheckBoxIsChecked;
public ICommand CheckBoxIsChecked
{
    get
    {
        if (_CheckBoxIsChecked == null)
        {
            _CheckBoxIsChecked = new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteCheckBoxIsChecked, CanExecuteCheckBoxIsChecked);
        }

        return _CheckBoxIsChecked;
    }
}
public bool CanExecuteCheckBoxIsChecked(object parameter)
{
    return true;
}
public void ExecuteCheckBoxIsChecked(object parameter)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

    if (parameter != null)
    {
        //Do Stuff...
    }

    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `TypeListViewStyle` and `CheckBoxStyleBase2` code

Comment: Please also check output console for binding related error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should get executed provided that the `CheckBoxIsChecked` property belongs to the data object where the `Value` and `Active` properties are defined.

If it belongs to the view model, you could bind to it using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckbReferralIsChecked" Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding Active}"
            Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyleBase2}"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxIsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. CheckBoxIsChecked is in the view model whereas Value and Active were in the model.

Comment: I posted a follow up question about the correct way to add the CommandParameter. I took a guess, but it's not quite right... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435313/wpf-commandparameter-relativesource-binding